# Firebase realtime database don't retrieve specified child

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I have db structure like this:

```
datas
-data1
--name
--city
--date
--logs
---log1
---log2
---log3

-data2
--name
...
```

Now, I released putting 'logs' inside 'data' parent was a huge mistake because its user generated child and growing up fast (so much data under it) and causes delay on downloading 'data1' parent naturally.

Normally I am pulling 'data1' with this:

```
database().ref('datas/' + this.state.dataID).on('value', function(snapshot) {

... })
```

I hope i could explain my problem, I just basically ignore 'logs' child (I need name,city,date)
As there project started and users already using this, I need a proper way.

Is there a way to do this on firebase side ?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you'll have an easy way out of this one...

> Queries are deep by default: they always return the entire subtree.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/rtdb-vs-firestore#querying

I can see only two options:

1. Migrate the logs to a different location (if it's really a huge amount of data, you could use something like BiqQuery https://cloud.google.com/bigquery or if it's events, you could store them in Google Analytics, it really depends on the volume and type of logs)
2. Attach multiple listeners instead of a single one (depending on the amount of entries that might be a viable interim solution):

   ```
    let response={
          name:null,
          city:null,
          date:null
       }
       const refs = ['name', 'city', 'date'].map(key=>database().ref(`datas/${this.state.dataID}/${key}')

       refs.forEach(ref=>ref.on('value',snapshot=>{

    })
   ```